# Fetching last 30 days data from mysql table and grouping them by date

Tags: php, mysql

Here is how my table looks like

```
| total_hit   |success_hit  | date_time             |
|      12     |          12 | 01-11-2009 07:32:44   | 
|      12     |          11 | 01-11-2009 08:33:49   | 
|      12     |          10 | 01-11-2009 09:08:24   | 
|      12     |          11 | 01-12-2009 10:33:57   | 
|      12     |          12 | 01-12-2009 11:37:34   | 
|      12     |          11 | 01-12-2009 12:23:49   |
```

I am fetching the data from the table for the past 30 days using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE DATE(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

what I want to do is group the returned data in terms of date and calculate the percentage success `(success_hit/total_hit)*100`
Something like

```
Date: 01-11-2009 Percentage: x
Date: 01-12-2009 Percentage: y
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT (sum(success_hit)/sum(total_hit)*100) AS `Percentage`,
       DATE(date_time) AS `Date`
FROM my_table
WHERE DATE(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY DATE(date_time);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select (success/total)*100 as perc_success, Date(date_time) from 
       (select sum(success_hit) as success, sum(total_hit) as total, 
            date_time from my_table
            where DATE(date_time) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
            group by Date(date_time)  ) 
tbl
```

This should work!!!